# nextcloud: sync one subfolder to a different location

Tags: debian, sync, nextcloud

I'm syncing my nextcloud to my local disk on multiple linux computers.
this nextcloud folder has tens of gigabyte data, most of them are within a single subfolder.

one of the computers has a smallish SSD-disk (where the system and `/home` reside) and a bigger data disk.
the `/home` partition is too small to hold the entire nextcloud folder, so I would like to move *parts* of the nextcloud folder (the one folder that contains the tens of gigabyte of data) to the data disk.

unfortunately i haven't found a way to specify the sync location for a specific subfolder only (it seems that it's only possible to set the sync location for the entire client).

i decidedly do *not* want to move my entire nextcloud folder to the big data disk.

is there a way?

or do i have to configure two accounts (that refer to the same account) and use different excludes for synching different folders to different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops, i just found out that the `Add Folder Sync Connection` does *exactly* what i am asking for.

it remove any previously downloaded data (so when re-organizing a synched folder into multiple sync-connections you have to re-download), but apart from that it seems to work fine.